# React SetState Array with function

Tags: reactjs, arrays

I have an array I wish to keep track of,

```
const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([]);
```

I want this to be an array of ***MyCustomObject***

I am then creating the array in my useEffect():

```
const newObject = new MyCustomObject(); //initiate object and set values (removed to simplify)

setMyArray(newObject);
```

I want to override myArray rather than push onto the list. How do I do this?

**EDIT:**

I think my initial code example was misleading. I've now copy/pasted my actual code for full transparency of the problem..

```
//this is imported further above
//    import CustomerTradeDto from "Models/Customer/CustomerTradeDto";
  const [arrayOfCustomerProviderRefTrades, setArrayOfCustomerProviderRefTrades] = useState([]);

      useEffect(() => {
        const newArray = customer.customerProviderRefList.map((providerRef) => {
            return {
                customersWithTrade: customerTradeList.customerTradeList.find(trade => trade.customerProviderRef == providerRef.externalRefId)
                 }
                })
setArrayOfCustomerProviderRefTrades([...arrayOfCustomerProviderRefTrades, newArray]);
              });
```

Error I am receiving: Type '{ customersWithTrade: CustomerTradeDto | undefined; }[]' is not assignable to type 'never'

Comment: You mean like `setMyArray([newObject]);`?

Comment: do you mean you want: (a) myArray to be a one-element array with your new item only or (b) you want myArray to be a new copy of the array with the previous items and your new item on the end?

Comment: @BenClayton, newObject should be an array (it's values are set later in useEffect(), and I then want to assign it as the value of my global const myArray.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have array of object and want to override one object of it with new one

you can do it by using prevState and findIndex

like this:

```
  const [myArray, setMyArray] = useState([]);
  const newObject = new MyCustomObject();

  setMyArray((prevState)=>{
    let newArr = prevState;
    if(newArr.length === 0 ){
      return [newObject]
    }
    let arrIndex = newArr.findIndex(item => item.id === newObject.id)
    if(arrIndex !== -1){
      newArr[arrIndex] = newObject
    }
    return newArr
  });
```

and if newObject is array of new objects you can have a loop for it

like this:

```
setMyArray((prevState)=>{
    let newArr = prevState;
    if(newArr.length === 0 ){
      return [newObject]
    }
    newObject.forEach(obj=>{
      let arrIndex = newArr.findIndex(item => item.id === obj.id)
      if(arrIndex !== -1){
        newArr[arrIndex] = obj
      }
    })

    return newArr
  });
```

and for typescript error you can set typeof arrayOfCustomerProviderRefTrades state in this way :

```
  const [arrayOfCustomerProviderRefTrades, setArrayOfCustomerProviderRefTrades] = useState<Array<{ customersWithTrade: CustomerTradeDto | undefined }[]>>([]);
```

Comment: i want to override the entire array

Comment: I updated my answer, let me know if it's what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

You should use the spread operator.

Try this

```
setMyArray([...newObject]);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Just edited the code example - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You want the state to be an array of an object, so set the state likewise.

### Solution

```
setMyArray([...myArray, newObject])
```

This should work smoothly.

Comment: I just edited my code to show you a better example. Any ideas?